# pythonanywhere - webpy serving static files(css/image)

Tags: python-2.7, web.py, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy a small application using webpy framework in [pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com)  but I have a problem in which I can't load the css file. Not found(404). My css file can be found in my /home/user232/main/webpy/static/main.css directory.

```
        $def with (page)
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Base</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/user232/main/webpy/static/main.css" media="screen" />
        </head>
        <body>
        ....
```

Also, tried putting the /static/main.css in var/www/ and use the href="static/main.css" but to no avail.

---

Solved: guys from pythonanywhere suggested to put the directory link of my static files in web tab for security reasons and access it using /static/main.css